# Лень и леность

Tags: лексика

В чем разница между понятиями "лень" (как черта характера) и "леность"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще говоря, разница очень зыбкая. Но если очень хочется её найти, то леность - черта характера, качество вообще. А лень - его проявление, обычно в конкретных случаях, по конкретному поводу.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы добавил, что слово "леность" имеет книжный характер в отличие от общеупотребительного "лень"