# Лень и леность — как свойство характера. В чем разница?

Tags: значение-слов

И лень, и леность — слова для обозначения черты характера. А есть ли разница между этими понятиями?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже было, вот здесь:[Лень и леность](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7623/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)